# WYGWAM causing Undefined property: EE::$view on validation failure of Channel Form

Tags: safecracker, wygwam, validation

I'm using the latest version of ExpressionEngine (2.9.2) and the latest version of WYGWAM (3.3.3).

I've a Channel Form which includes the WYGWAM field and when I submit the form I receive the following error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: EE::$view

Filename: libraries/File_field.php

Line Number: 704

Fatal error: Call to a member function head_link() on a non-object in /Users/joe/Sites/mywebsite/webroot/5ystem/expressionengine/libraries/File_field.php on line 704
```

However, I've noticed a few things:

1) I only receive the message if the form has validation errors, otherwise it submits fine and the record appears in the channel as expected

2) If I remove error_handling="inline" from the form declaration then the errors are displayed fine, albeit not inline

3) If I remove the WYGWAM field then this error does not occur, even if there are/aren't validation errors and if the error_handling="inline" is/isn't included

Can anyone shed any light on this please?

The rest of the form declaration is:

```
{exp:channel:form channel="jobs" author_only="yes" error_handling="inline" return="jobs/success" class="channel-form" datepicker="no"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having spoken to Pixel & Tonic:

> All Wygwam does when you've got the native EE file manager selected to manage files is this:

```
// load the file browser
$EE->load->library('file_field');
$EE->file_field->browser();
```

> According to the error message, the actual error is occurring in libraries/File_field.php. If I had to guess, it would be an EE bug that has to do with anything using their native file manage on the front-end.

So, as a workaround, I've disabled inline validation and just added jQuery validation using Parsley.